# Rails: Upload Audio Files (mp3) with Paperclip, what am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Can somebody please explain to me how to upload audio files as attachments (specifically mp3 files) to a model in my rails app with Paperclip?

Ive been trying for ages and so far no luck (im going insane).

My rails app has only one model called Tracks (its very basic), I installed the paperclip gem and added this code to my tracks model,

```
has_attached_file :mp3
  validates_attachment_content_type :mp3, :content_type => { :content_type => ["audio/mpeg", "audio/mp3"] }, :file_name => { :matches => [/mp3\Z/]}
```

I then permitted the parameter in my controller, like so:

```
  private

  def track_params
    params.require(:track).permit(:title, :description, :mp3)
  end
```

Then I added it to my _form.html.erb, like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @track do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.file_field :mp3 %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now whenever I try to submit the form, it doesn't save, only renders the form again.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing?

Many thanks,

Ant

(full controller code below)

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_track, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @tracks = Track.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @track = Track.new
  end

  def create
    @track = Track.new(track_params)

    if @track.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @track.update(track_params)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @track.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def track_params
    params.require(:track).permit(:title, :description, :mp3)
  end

  def find_track
    @track = Track.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Here is the rails server code when from creating a new track to submitting the form..

```
Started GET "/tracks/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-18 12:51:19 +0200
Processing by TracksController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Genre Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "genres".* FROM "genres"
  Rendering tracks/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered tracks/_form.html.erb (7.3ms)
  Rendered tracks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 91ms (Views: 82.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)


Started POST "/tracks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-18 12:51:58 +0200
Processing by TracksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kbvYCPTwS1WdI4lK3xLsnNKkrxJFo+y3mmJUIrhr5ceWjYQyjfqsVUNllQC1Ih13erBOi7VFFtNfjFuyPyhDlg==", "track"=>{"title"=>"Hello Sunshine", "description"=>"Track for Acoustic Style Videos", "price"=>"1.99", "audio"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007feb1b300670 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/nn/k15ytbks3n30bk74txp8t2pc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170918-13484-qqppq1.mp3>, @original_filename="Gravity by John Mayer.mp3", @content_type="audio/mp3", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"track[audio]\"; filename=\"Gravity by John Mayer.mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n">}, "genre_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Create Track"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/var/folders/nn/k15ytbks3n30bk74txp8t2pc0000gn/T/a7583642b9fdf84dddb8dba14909ce6120170918-13484-c875vy.mp3'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Gravity_by_John_Mayer.mp3 (audio/mpeg from Headers, ["audio/mpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream. See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/var/folders/nn/k15ytbks3n30bk74txp8t2pc0000gn/T/a7583642b9fdf84dddb8dba14909ce6120170918-13484-1xhh8so.mp3'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Gravity_by_John_Mayer.mp3 (audio/mpeg from Headers, ["audio/mpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream. See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering tracks/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered tracks/_form.html.erb (9.7ms)
  Rendered tracks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 88ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):
    2: <%= simple_form_for @track do |f| %>
    3: <%= f.input :title, label: "Track Name:" %>
    4: <%= f.input :description %>
    5: <%= select_tag(:genre_id, options_for_select(@genres), :prompt => "Select a Genre", class: "genre_select") %>
    6: <%= f.input :price %>
    7: <%= f.file_field :audio %>
    8: <%= f.button :submit %>

app/views/tracks/_form.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_tracks__form_html_erb___4605380733745630_70323911562620'
app/views/tracks/_form.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_tracks__form_html_erb___4605380733745630_70323911562620'
app/views/tracks/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_tracks_new_html_erb___4047185287574205786_70323904027580'
app/controllers/tracks_controller.rb:34:in `create'
```

Comment: add code to your form `<%= @track.errors.full_messages %>` to show errors.

Answer (score 1):

For all mp3 content type validations use the following mimetypes:

```
    validates_attachment_content_type :audio,
  :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]
```

Or

You can remove the validation and then check in database how the content type is being saved and add that validation.

**Content Type Spoof issue**

create `paperclip.rb` file in `config/initializers`

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  :mp3 => "application/octet-stream"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I changed my code to your suggestion, but the problem I appear to be having is that its not actually saving the file to the database. I have validated the audio file in my model and also my controller, but when I submit the form, all audio values remain as nil in the database, any suggestions? Thanks - @Hammad Maqbool

Comment: @AntChamberlin can you paste rails server log here, when you submit the form?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hammad. I have pasted the rails server code at the bottom of my original question. Thanks! @Hammad Maqbool

Comment: @AntChamberlin you have Content Type Spoof issue

check my updated answer for that issue resolution.

Comment: I created the file with the suggested code and unfortunately not resolved. The problem I'm having is that the mp3 file I upload doesn't save into my tracks table after I have submitted the form. I have permitted the :audio in my tracks controller but not sure where else to turn. @Hammad Maqbool